# How disable Ctrl+A,Ctrl+C key functions in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to disable ctrl+c and other ctrl options inside iframe how to achieve this

i got code for disabling in webpage but its not working inside iframe. How to change this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language="JavaScript">

//////////F12 disable code////////////////////////
    document.onkeypress = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
           //alert('No F-12');
            return false;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            //alert('No F-keys');
            return false;
        }
    }
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            //alert('No F-keys');
            return false;
        }
    }
/////////////////////end///////////////////////


//Disable right click script 
//visit http://www.rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/ 
var message="Sorry, right-click has been disabled"; 
/////////////////////////////////// 
function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}} 
function clickNS(e) {if 
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) { 
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}} 
if (document.layers) 
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;} 
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;} 
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false") 
// 
function disableCtrlKeyCombination(e)
{
//list all CTRL + key combinations you want to disable
var forbiddenKeys = new Array('a', 'n', 'c', 'x', 'v', 'j' , 'w');
var key;
var isCtrl;
if(window.event)
{
key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
if(window.event.ctrlKey)
isCtrl = true;
else
isCtrl = false;
}
else
{
key = e.which;     //firefox
if(e.ctrlKey)
isCtrl = true;
else
isCtrl = false;
}
//if ctrl is pressed check if other key is in forbidenKeys array
if(isCtrl)
{
for(i=0; i<forbiddenKeys.length; i++)
{
//case-insensitive comparation
if(forbiddenKeys[i].toLowerCase() == String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase())
{
alert('Key combination CTRL + '+String.fromCharCode(key) +' has been disabled.');
return false;
}
}
}
return true;
}
</script>


</head>

<body onkeypress="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);" onkeydown="return disableCtrlKeyCombination(event);">
<iframe  src="document" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

How to change this to work for iframe.I need to disable CTRL+A CTRL+C CTRL+V etc

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with php. Tag properly your question to receive useful help.

Comment: Have you tried attaching your `onkeypress`/`onkeydown` attributes to the page you load into your iframe? You'll need the javascript function in there too.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP, what is disabling the ctrl key supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Nothing I hate more than a website disabling native functionality. If I want to copy some text, just let me. Anyway, is the page *within* the `iframe` on your server? Ie. Do you have access to the URL? 'Cause you're going to need to include that same JavaScript into the iFrame'd page as well.

Comment: It seems you're trying to prevent opening the console and copying data. Plot twist: if the user can show the page, their computer has already received said data. People who want to steal your content will find a way around those tricks, and people who want to use it under fair use will be angry. Don't do this. Ever.

Comment: Oh, and the fact that this code looks horribly-formatted, outdated, breaks standards and contains commented links to a script-sharing site shows that you aren't trying to solve a problem but only looking for people who can provide you with code. StackOverflow is a problem-solving site, not a place to ask others to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script is in the `<head>` section.

You might also want to try this script which helps me for my email marketing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=false;
}
document.onkeydown=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=true;
if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) &amp;&amp; isCtrl == true)
{
// alert(&#8216;Keyboard shortcuts are cool!&#8217;);
return false;
}
}
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
function mischandler(){
return false;
}
function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
</script>
```

Enjoy.
It might sounds stupid, but yeah it works.